# Error passing function to child component react (Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: result is not a function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I want to pass the result from an api call made on the child component to parent component so:

PARENT:

```
const Parent = () => {

    function logFunction(resultFromAPI) {
        console.log(resultFromAPI);
    }

    return(
        <Child result={ logFunction }  />
    )
}

export default Parent
```

CHILD COMPONENT

```
const Child = ({result}) => {

    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        name: ''
    })


    const handleChange = (name) => (event) => {
        setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
    };


    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        const response = await createApi(values);
        if (response.data.message) {
            setValues({
                name: "",
            });

            result(response.data); //Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: result is not a function
            
        }

        if (response.data.error) {
            toast("error", response.data.message);
        }
    };


    return(
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Input 
            name='name'
            value={name}
            onChange={handleChange("name")}
         />
    </form>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
    )
}

export default Child
```

The form sends the "name" value on clic of the button to the function "handleSubmit" the function call an API.

The then, i want to call the "result" function from the child props. Put the result from the api on the function and log it on the parent.

But I got the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: result is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that the "result" prop passed from the parent component to the child component is not a function.

Here are a few things you can try:

Verify the type of the "result" prop passed to the child component:
console.log(typeof result);

Make sure that the "logFunction" function is passed as a prop to the child `component: return ( <Child result={logFunction} /> );`

Make sure that you are calling the "result" function correctly:
`result(response.data);`

If you still encounter the error after trying these steps, please check the rest of your code and make sure that there are no other issues.

Comment: I did everything you write but the error reminds… there is nothing wrong with the rest of the code … the function works in parent , and in child (by its own) the error appears when I put the “function” as prop … and tried to call it from child …

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my code recently, i didn't notice that i was rendering multiple children and was not passing props to all of then.

Make sure you are passing the function where you need it, also try console.logging

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35509282)